# Run As administrator installed application does not install to the User profile logged in? And shortcut question

Tags: windows-7, installation, uac, administrator

Windows 7
Why would the restrictions of UAC keep an application from installing to a regular user profile?
Run as administrator installs to the administrator user's profile running the install. Is it really necessary to login to that profile to actually find the application?
Am I missing something beyond providing  permitted user credentials?

If there are administrative only apps why are there ANY administrative tools anywhere for a regular user?

As a follow up, this reminded me to ask...
 When I have a shortcut which is set to RUN as an administrative user, how come it won't just do that? Why is it necessary to verify? It would seem the the method for assigning permissions should make for less steps and yet it isn't. I am a recent XP user with the bad habit of running as admin, and am trying to remedy my ways.

```
What am I missing?
```

I have worked hard to not turn off UAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Run as administrator installs to the
>   administrator user's profile running
>   the install.

wrong, this will not install in the user's "profile running the install" but in the built-in  Administrator account (which is hidden by default). this is not the same as a user account with administrative rights.

this account is best left alone. create another account with administrative rights and use the option "Run as a different user".

*to execute a command as different user in Windows 7 use "shift + right click".*

[image]

Comment: You are correct. I missed that. What I hoped to do is install, at minimum a shortcut, that could be run by administrative users without having to login to a different profile. That is what I would expect. What you describe seems to be what is going on.